# What is the usage of override in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I still don't understand the usage of override in solidity.
I know the how to write code of override, but I have no idea when I should use them.

Question 1: Is it just for write less code in inherited contract?
Question 2: If I override the function in son-contract, would it affect the function of father-contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Is it just for write less code in inherited contract?*

Generally, you can use overriding if you want to change a default behavior. Here goes a silly example that assumes most vehicles have a steering wheel, so that's the default option - but it's overridden for motorbikes.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Vehicle {
    function turnRight() virtual external {
        turnSteeringWheel();
    }
}

contract Car is Vehicle {
    // no need to override turning, car has a steering wheel
}

contract Motorbike is Vehicle {
    // motorbike has a handlebar - not a steering wheel
    // so turning a steering wheel would not work
    function turnRight() override external {
        turnHandlebar();
    }
}
```

Overriding is also useful when you let someone else expand on your code. For example the OpenZeppelin ERC20 [implementation](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.8.1/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87) allows you to override their default number of decimals.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MyT") {}

    function decimals() override public pure returns (uint8) {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

> *If I override the function in son-contract, would it affect the function of father-contract?*

The function in the parent contract is not executed, unless the parent function is explicitly called with the `super` keyword.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract Parent {
    function foo() virtual public pure returns (uint) {
        return 1;
    }
}

contract Child is Parent {
    // not calling the Parent function, returning 2
    function foo() override public pure returns (uint) {
        return 2;
    }
}

contract Child2 is Parent {
    // calling the Parent function from within the Child function
    function foo() override public pure returns (uint) {
        uint returnedFromParent = super.foo();

        // 1 plus 1, returns 2
        return returnedFromParent + 1;
    }
}
```